# Finding items in array within range in non naive approach

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to solve this problem in none naive approach but nothing came to my mind, could please somebody give some hints
find employees who badged into our secured room unusually often. We have an unordered list of names and access times over a single day. Access times are given as three or four-digit numbers using 24-hour time, such as "800" or "2250"
Write a function that finds anyone who badged into the room 3 or more times in a 1-hour period, and returns each time that they badged in during that period. (If there are multiple 1-hour periods where this was true, just return the first one.

```
   String[][] badgeTimes = new String[][] {
        {"Paul",     "1355"},
        {"Jennifer", "1910"},
        {"John",      "830"},
        {"Paul",     "1315"},
        {"John",     "1615"},
        {"John",     "1640"},
        {"John",      "835"},
        {"Paul",     "1405"},
        {"John",      "855"},
        {"John",      "930"},
        {"John",      "915"},
        {"John",      "730"},
        {"John",      "940"},
        {"Jennifer", "1335"},
        {"Jennifer",  "730"},
        {"John",     "1630"},
      };
```

Expected output:
John: 830 835 855 915 9
Paul: 1315 1355 1405

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do here is the following:

1. Restructure the data to have an array for each employee that contains the times of that employee (assuming name are unique).
2. While doing step #1, make sure to add leading '0's when necessary to get all times into 4 characters.
3. Sort these lists (fairly easy when all items have 4 characters).
4. Go over the list and for each item check if there are two more items and if the second one is within an hour.

Done.

Comment: This is simulation. You are looking at code which will go in O(n^2).

Edit: Actually O(n^2logn) - Due to sorting of the list

Answer (score 0):

I did this question by simulation. Looking for a better solution.
Algo:
Convert the array into map of list of integer(to help with easy calculation later).

Iterate over the map, sort each list, and then loop over it, to check any point in time which can have 3 or more badge times). Add all those to return list.

```
static Map<String, List<String>>  solve(String [][] bt) {
    Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < bt.length; i++) {
      List<Integer> list = map.getOrDefault(bt[i][0], new ArrayList<>());
      list.add(Integer.parseInt(bt[i][1]));
      map.put(bt[i][0], list);
    }
    // Todo handle corner cases
    Map<String, List<String>> result  = new HashMap<>();
    
    for(Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      List<Integer> times = entry.getValue();
      if(times.size()< 3){
        continue;
      } else {
        Collections.sort(times, (a,b) -> Integer.compare(a,b));
        List<String> resultTemp = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < times.size(); i++) {
          int val =  times.get(i);
          int nextVal = i+2< times.size() ? times.get(i+2) : 2600;
          if(nextVal - val <= 100) {
            // candidate
            resultTemp = new ArrayList<>();
            int j = i; 
            int temp = times.get(i);
            while( j < times.size() && temp - val <= 100 ) {
              resultTemp.add(String.valueOf(temp));
              temp = times.get(j++);
            }
            break;
          }
          
        }
        if(resultTemp.size() > 0)
          result.put(entry.getKey(), resultTemp);  
      }
    }
    
    return result;
    
    
  }
```